# Drupal: Create a verticale-tab item for Add/Edit page

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7

I am building a new module for Drupal 7. Now I'm trying to add a "vertical-tab" item on the admin page where pages are being added/edited. (Current items are "Publisher", "Menu settings", "URL path settings").

I think it's possible to "hook" a new item from the module to that menu, but I couldn't find a full hint/answer to get there.

Thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it's possible to "hook" a new item from the module to that menu, but I couldn't find a full hint/answer to get there.

Use hook_form_alter() or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() to change form.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

E.g implement on of this hooks in the your module. For example:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id != 'my_form_id') {
    return;
  }
  // ...
  // Make your form changes here.
}
```

or

```
function mymodule_form_my_form_id_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // ...
  // Make your form changes here.
}
```

Use dpm($form) (from the devel module) or just print_r($form) (but dpm() function is very convenient) to inspect form structure and decide what changes and where you need.

Comment: Thanks, in combination with the other answer I've created a new tab with my content.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code inside the setting form of admin page to add item in "vertical tab"

`$form['settings'] = array(
'#type' => 'vertical_tabs',
);`